# segue destinationViewController doesn't return the correct navigation controller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I have a button in a UITableViewCell for each row. When pressing this button, the user should go to another view controller.
I connected the button action to the new view controller.

In the code I use: [segue destinationViewController] to get the destination view controller.

For some reason the destination view controller is not return, but an instance of: UINavigationController is return.

Does anyone know why it happens?

Here is a screenshot of my StoryBoard. I want to go from the top view controller to the bottom view controller.

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide screenshot of this part of your storyboard?

Comment: Thanks. I added a screenshot. I hope it is clear enough.

Comment: Hi Saviatoslav, did you have a chance of looking in the attached storyboard?

Comment: Sorry, storyboard did not help.

Comment: The question is if I am doing something wrong. You can see that there are several tabs in the app. Each tab has its own navigation controller, but when clicking a button in a table row I allow navigating to another view controller that has a different view controller.